# Choose last webElement from list

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Taught it could be simple, but got stuck. Could someone please assist me in following:
Need to pickup just last element from list (and no other else). Found all elements:

```
List<WebElement> all1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main[@class='main row']/article/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ol[1]//a"));
```

Tried with this to pickup last:

```
WebElement lastElement = all.get(all.size() - 1);
```

Got following error as a result of running test:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBounds -1
```

What I did wrong? Thank you in advance

[image]

HTML:

```
<article>
<p><strong>If you earn yourself a prize/strong></p>
<div class="row">
<div class="row">
 <div style="width:100%; height:0; position: relative; padding-   bottom:56.25%"><iframe src="//site13251226.23video.com/v.ihtml   /player.html?token=4e11b3a23e3bb16ec53f380619c36c93&amp;source=embed&amp; photo%5fid=19283817" style="width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute; top:  0; left: 0;" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="1"  mozallowfullscreen="1" webkitallowfullscreen="1"></iframe></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <p></p><div class="row">
 <div class="promotion">
 <h2 class="promotion-header competition-title">month <span>Prize:   £3000</span></h2>
 <div class="promotion-body competition">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="large-8 column">
 <div class="t-box-padding">
 <p>How well do you know .</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="large-4 column trophy padding-reset text-center">
 <img src="">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="large-12 column">
 <p class="prize">Prize: <strong>£3000</strong></p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <h2>Current standings <small>( 1. Jan 2018 - 1. Feb 2018)</small></h2>
  <ol class="competition-standings">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
 <li class="list-item row">
```

Comment: `findElements` returned an empty list, there are no elements matching this `xpath`.

Comment: @Guy - quite oposite, there are found. View screenshot

Comment: If `all.size() - 1` is `-1`, than `all.size()` is `0`.

Comment: @Guy - what then with screenshot - it shows that I found elements. Not getting this. So far, it worked as a charm (when using this online tool)

Comment: Add the html to you question.

Comment: Are those elements inside the `<iframe>`? if they are, you need to switch to it.

Comment: @Guy - added HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution - muy mistake - wrong xpath were chosen and correct is:

```
List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main[@class='main row']/article/div/div[1]/div//ol[1]/li/div[@class='column large-6 competition-standings-user ellipsis']/a"));
```